# Javascript combine multiple arrays from different scopes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

below is a function which should use `chaptersArry` to get each chapters items and put them in to a new array **with the original chapter data and items data together** called `itemsArr`

```
function get_items(chaptersArry){
  for ( var ii = 0, l = chaptersArry.length; ii < l; ii++ ) {
    console.log(chaptersArry[ii].id+" *****");  // this returns the correct data


    // now I am using each chapter ID from above to $.get the chapter items..... 
    var api_url = '/collections/' + chaptersArry[ii].id + '/contents.json';
    $.get(api_url, function(items) {
      // for each chapter loop through items and push them to itemsArr.
      for ( var i = 0, l = items.collection_contents.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        console.log(chaptersArry[ii].id); // returns incorrect data 
        itemsArr.push({
            series_id : chaptersArry[ii].series_id, 
            series_name : chaptersArry[ii].series_name,
            chapter_id : chaptersArry[ii].id, 
            chapter_name : chaptersArry[ii].name,
            chapter_display_name : chaptersArry[ii].display_name,
            chapter_data : items.collection_contents[i]
        });
      }
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: I think [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with Kamyar Infinity's answer, you need to use a closure or use block scoping with `let` to get the correct data inside your `$.get()` callback, however, that is not the crux of the issue. Since you are needing to return data asynchronously, you need to use promises. Here is how you can do that:

### [Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/xokajequwe/2/edit?js,console)

```
function get_items(chaptersArry){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var promises = [];
    for (let ii = 0, l = chaptersArry.length; ii < l; ii++ ) {
      console.log(chaptersArry[ii].id+" *****");  // this returns the correct data

      // now I am using each chapter ID from above to $.get the chapter items..... 
      var api_url = '/collections/' + chaptersArry[ii].id + '/contents.json';
      var promise = new Promise(function (_resolve, _reject) {
        $.get(api_url, function(items) {
          var itemsArr = [];
          // for each chapter loop through items and push them to itemsArr.
          for ( var i = 0, l = items.collection_contents.length; i < l; i++ ) {
            itemsArr.push({
              series_id : chaptersArry[ii].series_id, 
              series_name : chaptersArry[ii].series_name,
              chapter_id : chaptersArry[ii].id, 
              chapter_name : chaptersArry[ii].name,
              chapter_display_name : chaptersArry[ii].display_name,
              chapter_data : items.collection_contents[i]
            });
          }
          _resolve(itemsArr);
        });
      });
      promises.push(promise);
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(function (values) {
      resolve(values);
    });
  });
}

get_items(chaptersArry).then(function (results) {
  // flatten array of results from each $.get()
  console.log([].concat(...results));
});
```

Comment: nice!. I am so close but `chaptersArry.length` returns `0` but when I inspect `chaptersArry` (in the same spot) it has a length of 6.... grrrrr — any idea why that might be?

Comment: @Omar I'm not sure what you are referring to. What do you mean the length is 0? Where is it 0? What does the `console.log(results)` at the bottom display for you? It is working for me with sample data. I will update my post with a working demo

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I see is, as you're using `var`, the value of `ii` will be `l-1` when the loop ends, as `var` is not block based declaration, and all of your functions will get the value for the same variable. Now, you have two options.

You can use `let`, if you can use ES6:

```
for ( let ii = 0, l = chaptersArry.length; ii < l; ii++ ) {
...
```

If not, you can use `IIFE`:

```
for ( var ii = 0, l = chaptersArry.length; ii < l; ii++ ) {
    (function(ii){
       ...
     })(ii);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
$.get(api_url, function(items) {
  var ii = this;
  // for each chapter loop through items and push them to itemsArr.
  for ( var i = 0, l = items.collection_contents.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    console.log(chaptersArry[ii].id); // returns incorrect data 
    itemsArr.push({
        series_id : chaptersArry[ii].series_id, 
        series_name : chaptersArry[ii].series_name,
        chapter_id : chaptersArry[ii].id, 
        chapter_name : chaptersArry[ii].name,
        chapter_display_name : chaptersArry[ii].display_name,
        chapter_data : items.collection_contents[i]
    });
  }
}.bind(ii));
```

There are better solutions to this problem. But this may be the simplest. This is possibly a duplicate since it is JavaScript closure related.